# Obj-C: Error trying to store indirect pointer as iVar

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I have been asked to create a method with a signature that resembles this:

```
- (void)updateLocation:(CLLocation**)location atInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval untilDate:(NSDate*)finishDate;
```

The idea is that a user passes in the address of a variable that I update from my class.  So, I need to store the location argument as an iVar, only when I try to create the iVar, I receive the error:

> > Pointer to non-const type 'CLLocation *' with no explicit ownership.

How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't do this.
2. The problem is in automatic reference counting: ARC needs to know ownership semantics of the pointee. Solution: Make argument's and instance variable's type `CLLocation * __strong *`.
3. **Again, don't!** The proposed architecture breaks encapsulation and should be rejected as bad design. Use delegation or notifications instead.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks! I didn't know you could put ownership qualifiers between the asterisks like that.  I don't have much say over the design and architecture (the lead is fairly stubborn), and there are several architectural issues that I disagree with on this project, but thank you for your advice.

Comment: No, you really should not do this. The design is so utterly broken, you should confront the person who's proposing this. At least point him to this reply.